# kill my previous file on local host

Tags: node.js, npm, localhost

I connected my file "smap" to **localhost:3000** couple month ago when I was learning the npm.

Right now, I cannot remove it from **localhost:3000**

It keeps showing me old file:

> smap@1.0.0 start /Users/Han
>   cross-env NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/hjs-dev-server
>   Listening at http://localhost:3000
>   webpack built 2f3c2c9a3eec810b8e79 in 2453ms

Does anyone know how can I remove it from my local host? I tried

```
Find: lsof -i :3000
Kill: kill -9 <PID>
```

but it did not work.

Since I get a new file, want to connect it with localhost.

Comment: "it keep showing me the old file" << when? What command are you issuing which shows you this output, and what would you expect instead?

Comment: I got a new file and want to try it on my localhost:3000. but when I load localhost:3000 on Chrome, it show my old work, "smap". i use the command cd dekstop, cd "new folder name", npm install, npm run. but it is still smap.

Comment: Are you sure the project name you set in your new project's `package.json` is not also `smap`?

Comment: 100% sure, they are totally different project. Is there anything else I can do? like reinstall something

Comment: Maybe you have a `package.json` in a folder *above* your project's folder and it belongs to `smap`? If `npm` doesn't find a `package.json` in the current folder, it will keep going upwards until it finds one and use that one. For example in `/Users/Han`...

Comment: you probably right. so how can I delete that package.json?

Comment: Well, just deleting the file should do it, but I guess it would be better (because I don't know for what the other file is in use) to just create a local package in your directory using `npm init` (not `npm install`!)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I got solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following commands?

**Find**: `sudo lsof -i tcp:3000`

**Kill**: `sudo kill -9 PID`